# DF analyse with Pandas in Python filter data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

hey stack overflow users,

i have the following problem. i have a table with informations about the incidence values of the individual countries.

I want to display the data in such a way that I can compare the incidence values of the USA with Germany, for example.

my problem is that the incidence values are accumulated. How can I filter out only the values of USA & Germany from the column day = 14.

As a result I want to see only the 14 days values in the respective rows, so that I can draw a temporal comparison of the incidence values.

DATA PREVIEW:

[image]

Comment: kindly provide [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try:

```
m=(df['day'].isin([7,14,21,28])) & (df['countriesAndTerritories'].isin(['USA','Germany']))
#If the names are exact 'USA' and 'Germany'
#OR
m=(df['day'].isin([7,14,21,28])) & (df['countriesAndTerritories'].str.contains('USA|Germany',case=False))
#IF the names are in irregular case i.e some are in uppercase and some are in lowercase
```

Finally:

```
df[m]
#OR
df.loc[m]
```

Comment: hey thanks for the answer ! how can i add in eq(14) more values like eq(7,14,21,28)?

Comment: @Work_fl0w updated answer....kindly have a look and pls tell if it works or not ***:)***

Comment: doesnt work it says : ValueError: Lengths must be equal

Comment: @Work_fl0w updated answer....added `()` in conditions kindly have a look ***:)***